# IIS application pool identity rejected with valid username/password

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am on Windows 7 and logged in with a different domain\username than I am trying to use for my IIS application pool.

I am unable to set my application pool identity to a custom account.  The error I get is:

`The specified password is invalid.  Please type a new password.`

The domain\username and password works fine in a remote desktop connection and I am able to connect to databases using `runas /netonly /user:domain\username ssms` command, so I know the username and password is good.

Why is IIS (IIS 7) specifically rejecting the account when it's otherwise good?  How would I troubleshoot this?

Note that I cannot browse the domain in question in Control Panel->User Accounts.  I *can* find it in Computer->Network->Search Active Directory.

Comment: add the user to IUSRS group

Comment: The user is in another domain/forest and I can't find it for some reason.

Comment: IIS can only support trust domains while other tools might support non trusted ones.

Comment: @LexLi that might be it.  I think the issue is that my workstation is on a domain that does not trust the other domain I'm trying to use as my IIS app pool identity.

Comment: check this 3 article- https://forums.iis.net/t/1213147.aspx?How+I+can+run+IIS+app+pool+by+domain+account+,  
      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#accessing-the-network,         https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/understanding-identities#understanding-configuration-isolation

Answer (score 0):

### **Issue**: Unable to access localhost

Service Unavailable

### HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

---

**How to Fix**: Denied due to changes in the system password.

1. Open IIS
2. Application Pools
3. DefaultAppPool -> Advanced Settings
4. Identity -> Click on three-dot (...)
5. Custom Account
6. Provide user name (as system name)
7. Password must be the system password
8. Restart the system

---

### For Default Website

1. Select website
2. Click on Connect as...
3. In Specific User tab, click on Set...
4. Provide : User name, Passowrd, and Confirm password as a system password
5. Restart the system